# django model inheritance & casting to subtype in a view

Tags: python, django

It's a sort of cms type application

I have an article model and some specializations in models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    DISPLAY_CHOICES = (
        ('N', 'None'),
        ('C','Carousel'),
        ('M','Marketing'),
        ('F','Featurette')
    ) 
    display = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = DISPLAY_CHOICES)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class Artist(Article):
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200,blank=True)

class Venue(Article):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    map_link = models.URLField(max_length=200,blank=True)

class Event(Article):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    performers = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
```

I want to render these in different ways depending on the value of article.display but when I call

```
articles.objects.all()
```

I still need the extra attributes form the subclasses so I wrote

```
#views.py
def castToSubClass(article):
    try:
        return Artist.objects.get(article_ptr_id = article.id)
    except:
        try:
            return Event.objects.get(article_ptr_id = article.id)
        except:
            try:
                return Venue.objects.get(article_ptr_id = article.id)
            except:
                return article


def index(request):
    carousel = [castToSubClass(article) for article in Article.objects.filter(display='C']
    marketing = [castToSubClass(article) for article in Article.objects.filter(display='M'[:3]]
    featurettes = [castToSubClass(article) for article in Article.objects.filter(display='F']
    return render_to_response('frontpage.html',
    {
    'carousel': carousel,
    'marketing':marketing,
    'featurettes': featurettes
    })
```

to turn them all in the appropriate subclass object, this apart from seeming clunky seems to mean I'm hitting the database twice for every (or nearly every) item in the queryset.

Is there a way to do this in the initial calls to the manager instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one model to store everything, and add a field to distinguish the article type, so that you can render different look for every type combine with *display* in the template(Like tumblr do).

```
class Article(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    DISPLAY_CHOICES = (
        ('N', 'None'),
        ('C','Carousel'),
        ('M','Marketing'),
        ('F','Featurette')
    ) 
    display = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = DISPLAY_CHOICES)
    ARTICLE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('artist', 'Artist'),
        ('venue', 'Venue'),
        ('event', 'Event'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices = ARTICLE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    map_link = models.URLField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    venue = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
    performers = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True)


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title


#views.py
def index(request):
    carousel = Article.objects.filter(display='C')
    marketing = Article.objects.filter(display='M')
    featurettes = Article.objects.filter(display='F')
    return render_to_response('frontpage.html',{'carousel': carousel, 'marketing':marketing, 'featurettes': featurettes})
```

Comment: thanks, trouble is... then I'll have to have a bunch of blank=True fields in the model.

Comment: There has to be a way to do it without the tremendous hazzle of combining already existing classes. If not, then the whole idea of subclassing models in Django should be deprecated.

Comment: This is about database structure design for specific requirements. Django model inheritance has it's specific situation.